# Why are they called Key,Value,Query-Vectors when they are actually matrices

Tags: attention-mechanism

Simple question really. People talk about K V Q Vectors when in a full attention all 3 are actually matrices (embed_size*sequence_length). So why the misnomer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those matrices can be seen as N vectors, each one of length `embed_size`, where N = `sequence_length`.